# Cannot set expire in private cookie Rocket-Rust

Tags: cookies, rust, rust-rocket

I'm trying to setting expire in private Cookie in Rust (Rocket Framework version 0.5.0-rc.1) using `rocket::http::Cookie`.

In rocket add_private doc I read:

> Unless a value is set for the given property, the following defaults are set on cookie before being added to self:
>
> ```
> path: "/"
> SameSite: Strict
> HttpOnly: true
> Expires: 1 week from now
> ```

I don't understand how to set the Expires property.

I tried to create a new cookie and setting expire using .set_expires() (as in doc [example](https://api.rocket.rs/master/rocket/http/struct.Cookie.html#method.set_expires)), but it gives me the error: "the trait `From<OffsetDateTime>` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<time::offset_date_time::OffsetDateTime>`". The code that return the error is something like (values here only for test purpose):

```
use rocket::http::{Cookie, CookieJar};
use cookie::time::{Duration, OffsetDateTime};

fn handler(jar: &CookieJar<'_>) {
    let mut cookie = Cookie::new("name", "value");

    let mut now = OffsetDateTime::now_utc();
    now += Duration::days(1);
    cookie.set_expires(now);

    jar.add_private(cookie);
}
```

I wonder if I have to use cookie crate instead of rocket::http to create the cookie, but in that case I cannot use CookieJar in the response handler because it expected a rocket::http::Cookie and not a cookie::Cookie.

Is there any other way to set an expire or a max age in private cookie using Rocket http module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this same problem and I think I've figured it out:

- Rocket uses both the `cookie` and `time` packages internally
- The example code in the Rocket docs for `rocket::http::Cookie` actually comes from the `cookie` package and therefor confusingly uses `use cookies::Cookie;` instead of `use rocket::http::Cookie`.
- **Key thing:** The docs at https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/ appear to be newer that the code that's in crates.io, and use different versions of the `cookie` and `time` crates.

So you need to use the same version or `cookie` or `time` that Rocket is using. If you're using rocket 0.5.0-rc.1 from crates.io then you need `cookie` 0.15 or `time` 0.2.11.

I was able to get my code working with these lines in my `Cargo.toml`:

```
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["secrets", "json"] }
time = "0.2.11"
```

Your example code would then become:

```
use rocket::http::{Cookie, CookieJar};
use time::{Duration, OffsetDateTime};

fn handler(jar: &CookieJar<'_>) {
    let mut cookie = Cookie::new("name", "value");

    let mut now = OffsetDateTime::now_utc();
    now += Duration::days(1);
    cookie.set_expires(now);

    jar.add_private(cookie);
}
```

Alternatively, I think if you use version 0.15 of `cookie` (you might be using 0.16.0-rc.1) then your code should work as you have it. I think it's cleaner to import `Duration` and `OffsetTime` directly from the `time` package though.

It looks like the latest version of Rocket in Github exposes `time` as `rocket::time` so we should be able to switch to that when final 0.5 release comes out.

Comment: Great, thank you! Using `Duration` and `OffsetTime` from `time` 0.2.11 makes the code works.